# Не работает пагинация в рубриках wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, пагинация

Не работает пагинация по записям в рубрике. При клике на след. страницу не меняются записи. Не корректное отображение колличества страниц пагинации с записями т.е. на странице 2 анонса всего 12 постов при отображении цифр пагинации выводит 16 страниц

```
<?php
$args = array (
    'cat' => 10,
    'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'page' )
    );
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php    query_posts( $query ); while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

<div class="news-view">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="main-wrap">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, array(200,200) ); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="news-txt">
        <p><?php the_excerpt_max_charlength(250); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">подробнее</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Было 3 ошибки. Итак поэтапно, что я сделал:
1. Создал для каждой рубрики страницу через админку и присвоил шаблон - этого делать нельзя пагинация ломается. Для рубрик вообще не надо создавать отдельные страницы через админку.
2. Нарушил иерархию шаблонов wordpress. Если вы создаете несколько рубрик и для каждой рубрики используете отдельный шаблон страницы то именуйте файлы category-(id-рубрики).php
 например category-10.php WP ищет в первую очередь эти страницы.
3. Не правильное определение переменной(только в моем случае) у остальных вроде как работает укороченный вариант записи

```
$paged = 1;
if(get_query_var('paged')) {
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif(get_query_var('page')) {
$paged = get_query_var('page');}
```

После всех манипуляций абсолютно любой тип пагинации стал корректно работать